# What can mutable do in C++?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

I was given this code on sequential programming and lock programming. I have to analyze the difference, but I’m not sure what some of the code is doing. The code is below, and the parts I don’t understand are also mentioned in the bullets.

- Effect of keyword: Mutable

  - Another StackOverflow answer says that mutable allows a const to be
    modified but I don’t see what that has to do with this project
  - What is the effect of removing “mutable” in this program? Does it disable 
    the locks?
- Mutable for not_full and not_empty

  - Furthering my lack of understanding of this, why is mutable not required for not_full and not_empty?

Thank you for reading, any help would be appreciated!

```
<pre><code>
    #ifndef LOCKEDBUFFER_H
    #define LOCKEDBUFFER_H

    #include <memory>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <atomic>

    #include "optional.h"

    template <typename T>
    class locked_buffer {
    public:
      // Creates buffer of size n
      locked_buffer(int n) :
        size_{n},
        buf_{new optional<T>[size_]}
      {
      }

      // Remove copy constructor
      locked_buffer(const locked_buffer &) = delete;

      // Destructor (default generated)
      ~locked_buffer() = default;

      // Gets buffer size
      int size() const noexcept {
        return size_;
      }

      // Checks if buffer is empty
      bool empty() const noexcept {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
        return is_empty();
      }

      // Checks if buffer is full
      bool full() const noexcept {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
        return is_full();
      }

      // Put an optional value in the queue
      void put(const optional<T> & x);

      // Get a value from the queue
      optional<T> get();

    private:
      // Next circular position to position p
      int next_position(int p) const noexcept {
        return p + ((p+1>=size_)?(1-size_):1);
      }

      // Check if buffer is empty without locking
      bool is_empty() const noexcept {
        return (next_read_ == next_write_);
      }

      // Check if buffer is full without locking
      bool is_full() const noexcept {
        const int next = next_position(next_write_);
        return next == next_read_;
      }

    private:
      const int size_;
      const std::unique_ptr<optional<T>[]> buf_;
      int next_read_ = 0;
      int next_write_ = 0;

      mutable std::mutex mut_;
      std::condition_variable not_full_;
      std::condition_variable not_empty_;
    };


    template <typename T>
    void locked_buffer<T>::put(const optional<T> & x) 
    {
      using namespace std;
      unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
      not_full_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_full(); });
      buf_[next_write_] = x;
      next_write_ = next_position(next_write_);
      not_empty_.notify_one();
    }

    template <typename T>
    optional<T> locked_buffer<T>::get()
    {
      using namespace std;
      unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
      not_empty_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_empty(); });
      auto res = buf_[next_read_];
      next_read_ = next_position(next_read_);
      not_full_.notify_one();
      return res;
    }

    #endif
```

Comment: i guess it is to enable locking the mutex also in `const` methods

Comment: `mutable` doesn't have anything to do with locks; removing it from this code will, at most, cause it to fail to compile.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through it step by step.

> Another StackOverflow answer says that mutable allows a const to be
>   modified but I don’t see what that has to do with this project

This does somehow apply to your class.
You have this method.

```
bool empty() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
    return is_empty();
}
```

The [lock guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) expects a non const object reference as the `lock_guard`will change the mutex.
But since your method is const you cannot access any member in a non const way. Here is where mutable comes into play.

> What is the effect of removing “mutable” in this program? Does it disable the locks?

If you remove the mutable from your `mutex` you will get a compile error in the `empty()` and the `full()` method. So technically the locks are not disabled but your program is ill formed.

> Furthering my lack of understanding of this, why is mutable not required for not_full and not_empty?

Well simply because they are used in non const methods.
So no need to make them mutable. If you would use any of them in a const method and you would like to use a non const method on the `condition_variable` then you would need to make them mutable.